# Urlencoding data for post request body. Am I using wrong charset?

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, http-post, iso-8859-1

I want to replicate a working POST request in Java. For testing purpose, lets take message like: '*äöõüäöõüäöõüäöõü*'

Working POST request (with encoded message of '*äöõüäöõüäöõüäöõü*'):

**Header**

```
POST http://www.mysite.com/newreply.php?do=postreply&t=477352 HTTP/1.1
Host: www.warriorforum.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 403
Origin: http://www.mysite.com
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko)Chrome/14.0.835.202 Safari/535.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Accept: */*
Referer: http://www.mysite.com/test-forum/477352-test.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: bblastvisit=1319205053; bblastactivity=0; bbuserid=265374; bbpassword=1125e9ec1ab41f532ab8ec6f77ddaf94; bbsessionhash=91444317c100996990a04d6c5bbd8375;
```

**Body**

`securitytoken=1319806096-618e5f9012901e2d818bf2c74c2121baa064be57&ajax=1&ajax_lastpost=1319806096&**message=%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC**&wysiwyg=0&styleid=1&signature=1&fromquickreply=1&s=&do=postreply&t=477352&p=who%20cares&specifiedpost=0&parseurl=1&loggedinuser=265374`

**As we can see in the request body '*äöõüäöõüäöõüäöõü* is encoded as:** `%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC`

Now i want to replicate it.

Lets Url encode the text with charset utf-8 in Java:

```
String userText = "äöõüäöõüäöõüäöõü";
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(userText, "utf-8");
```

**Result**: %C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B5%C3%BC%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B5%C3%BC%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B5%C3%BC%C3%A4%C3%B6%C3%B5%C3%BC%0A%0A%0A%5BSIZE%3D%221%22%5D%5BI%5D << NOT THE SAME

Lets try ISO-8859-1:

```
String userText = "äöõüäöõüäöõüäöõü";
String encoded = URLEncoder.encode(userText, "ISO-8859-1");
```

**Result**: %E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC%0A%0A%0A%5BSIZE%3D%221%22%5D%5BI%5D << NOT THE SAME

Neither of them produce the same encoded string as in the working example, but all of them have the same input. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC%u00E4%u00F6%u00F5%u00FC
```

I don't know what the above data is encoded as, but it isn't `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` as the request claims. This is not legal data for this MIME type.

It looks like some UTF-16BE-encoded form.

`URLEncoder.encode(userText, "utf-8");` would be the correct way to encode the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` values if this was actually what the server was expecting. ([ref](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1))

Comment: How would it to be possible for me to identify which type of encoding it is? Note: it is a POST request of a vBulletin forum running on version 3.8.7

Comment: @SYLAARR - it is unlikely that the browser is producing this data. I would look for JavaScript that creates this.

Comment: Thank you, you were right: vBulletin forum quick replay was encoding the message with somekind of another algorithm. Now I have run into another problem, maybe you can help me with this one to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058687/trying-to-replicate-a-successful-post-request-with-jsoup-data-posted-to-server