# Trying to replicate a successful POST request with JSoup - data posted to server does not get decoded

Tags: android, http, post, character-encoding, jsoup

**Http request header:**

```
Host: www.mysite.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: bbuserid=XXX; bbpassword=YYY; bbsessionhash=ZZZ
Content-Length: 252
```

**Http request body:**

```
message=%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC&securitytoken=XXX&do=postreply&t=483553
```

Working fine! Data posted to server gets decoded on the other end and user sees orginal message which is `äöõüäöõüäöõüäöõü`.

Now lets try to implement this excact example with JSoup:

```
//request body 
Map<String, String> datamap = new HashMap<String, String>();
datamap.put(Session.SESSION_SECURITYTOKEN,"XXX");
datamap.put("message", URLEncoder.encode(finalText, "ISO-8859-1"));
datamap.put("do", "postreply");
datamap.put("t", "483553");

//make a post
Jsoup.connect(url)
.header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.timeout(10000)
.cookie(Session.COOKIE_HASH_KEY,session.bbsessionhash)
.cookie(Session.COOKIE_PASSWORD_KEY,session.bbpassword)
.cookie(Session.COOKIE_USERID_KEY,session.bbuserid)
.data(datamap).post();
```

My message gets posted BUT it is not decoded by the server. So when user views the message he/she sees: `%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC%E4%F6%F5%FC`

Note: I am doing the post request from Android and posting data to vBulletin forum software (replay to thread).

**The problem:** When I send the message with JSoup, server sees it like a plain text not a encoded text. **How can I make the server to understand that the message parameter holds encoded text, not plain text?**

Comment: I am not familiar with Jsoup, but I imagine it is encoding its parameters in the `data` method. So using `URLEncoder.encode` on a value encodes the data twice.

Comment: Removing `URLEncoder.encode` adds plain text to message parameter and I'm losing specific characters which need encoding. The working POST request manages somehow to tell the server, that the message is encoded and you (server) have to decode it. But when I try to replicate it, server takes the message as a plain text. Any idea, how can I make the server to understand that the message parameter holds encoded text, not plain text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jsoup uses UTF-8 by default to URL-encode the query string. With the current API version, you cannot change it without rebuilding the source (it's the `org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil#defaultCharset` constant which is been used in `org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection` class). Best what you can do is to [post an issue report](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues) requesting the ability to preset the charset beforehand.

Until then, you could use [`HttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) or [`URLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) instead which allows for a more finer grained control over sending HTTP requests. You could finally feed its response as an `InputStream` to `Jsoup#parse()` method.

---

**Update**: if the target website supports it, you could try explicitly specifying the client's used charset in the `Content-Type` request header:

```
.header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
```

Note that you should **not** use `URLEncoder#encode()` yourself; let Jsoup do its job.

Comment: So do I get it right, that JSoup encodes every single HTTP POST body in UTF-8 automatically and it's not possible to change it (without editing the JSoup source code and recompiling the jar)?

Comment: That's correct. Jsoup is however a relatively new API and needs more finetuning to meet the sensible real world use cases better. New issues and feature requests are always welcome. See also the last paragraph of its `Connection` javadoc: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html As to the choice for UTF-8; that's most likely because Jsoup is designed to be a HTML5 parser and HTML5 mandates UTF-8 as default charset. Your target website is simply "outdated" in that perspective :)

Comment: Please see answer update; this will work if the target website supports that, but don't be surprised if this is not been respected by the target website (which would then actually be the target website's own fault).