# JSoup does not post data in ISO 8859 encoding

Tags: post, utf-8, jsoup, iso-8859-1

Is there any way to tell JSoup to post data using iso-8859-1 rather than utf-8 ?
I tried posting a parameter that contains the letter 'è' the my webserver receives the character with hex code C3A8 but I want to send E8.

The code I wrote is

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://somesite.com/test") .data("parameter1","\u00E8").
header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute()
                    .parse();
```

As already said, on the other hand I get a 2 bytes data (C3A8) rather than a single byte with E8 inside.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058687/trying-to-replicate-a-successful-post-request-with-jsoup-data-posted-to-server

Answer (score 0):

[Trying to replicate a successful POST request with JSoup - data posted to server does not get decoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058687/trying-to-replicate-a-successful-post-request-with-jsoup-data-posted-to-server)

Has an accepted answer, saying it is not possible to do it. You will have to find a way to post your code into utf-8. If you do not succeed in that, just open a new question about it.